# How to start remote Safari Technology Preview from Selenese Runner Java

Tags: selenium, safari

I have here a Selenium Hub and a Selenium Node with Config:

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "safari",
          "version": "10",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "webdriver.safari.driver": "/Applications/Safari\ Technology\ Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/safaridriver"
        }
      ],

    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 1,
    "port": 5555,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hub": "<IP>:4444",
    "role": "node",
}
```

If I try to start a test from a Maven project with the code:

```
SafariOptions safariOptions = new SafariOptions();  
safariOptions.setUseTechnologyPreview(true);
safariOptions.setUseCleanSession(true);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
capabilities.setCapability(SafariOptions.CAPABILITY, safariOptions);
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
    new URL("http://172.31.4.70:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities); 

System.out.println(capabilities.toString());
System.out.println(safariOptions.toJson().toString());

driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://check24.de/kredit");


//Close the browser
driver.quit();
```

On the MAC, the Safari Technology Preview starts no problem.
The Selenium Hub log:

```
14:02:03.874 INFO - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{browserName=safari, safari.options={technologyPreview=true, port=0, cleanSession=true}, version=, platform=MAC}]
14:02:03.898 INFO - Trying to create a new session on test slot {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, webdriver.safari.driver=/Applications/Safari Technology Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/safaridriver, browserName=safari, maxInstances=1, version=10, platform=MAC}
```

Now I'd like to start that with Selenese Runner Java with

```
java -jar C:\selenium\selenese-runner.jar --driver remote --remote-url http://<ip>:4444/wd/hub --remote-platform MAC --remote-browser "safari" --define "safari.options={technologyPreview=true, port=0, cleanSession=true}" --screenshot-on-fail C:\selenium\screenshot --max-time 600 --baseurl %1 %2
```

The log on the Seleniu Hub is the same:

```
14:05:26.088 INFO - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{browserName=safari, safari.options={technologyPreview=true, port=0, cleanSession=true}, version=, platform=MAC}]
14:05:26.102 INFO - Trying to create a new session on test slot {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, webdriver.safari.driver=/Applications/Safari Technology Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/safaridriver, browserName=safari, maxInstances=1, version=10, platform=MAC}
```

But a Safari (NOT Technology Preview) instante starts on the Selenium Node.

The different is that one send the safari.option with safariOption Class and one send it with plain text.

I cannot understand why there is defferent.

Have you any Idea?

Thanks!

Lian Shen